# Best ubuntu flavor for my system?

Tags: 10.04, xubuntu, dell-mini-10

I am pretty new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. I have a Dell Mini 10 with 1gb of RAM. 
Would like to know if it would be able to run Ubuntu 10.04 without any issues/lag or should I settle for something like Xubuntu? I would choose performance over graphics any day.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 10.04 is end of life and not supported anymore, if I remember correctly. If you want a long term solution, use 12.04.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 is currently at it's EOL stage, which means support is no longer offered for those running that system. In order to keep Ask Ubuntu a clean and up-to-date site, we tend to close questions regarding EOL (End of Life) versions of Ubuntu. You can refer [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) to find out more. When you gain enough [reputation you can discuss 10.04 in the chatrooms](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/chat). Otherwise, if you meant to say Ubuntu ***12.04*** then please edit your post :)

Comment: You'd better install Lubuntu 13.04 if you are looking for performance.

Comment: 10.04 is supported for 5 years, it is NOT eol, but it is the old LTS, so you should use 12.04 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about performance over graphics and you're new to Ubuntu and Linux, go with Lubuntu 12.04 LTS.  It will be more stable for you, and you'll find yourself troubleshooting issues far less.  You can get a little better performance from Lubuntu 13.04 because of the newer kernel and updated packages, but if you're new to Linux it probably isn't worth it.  That's my two cents, although I'm sure if you ask 10 people you'll get 10 different answers.

Definitely don't go with 10.04 for reasons already mentioned (it's EOL).  Also, it's WAY behind in kernel and package updates.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 10.04 is no longer supported. If you want a long term solution, install 12.04. Ubuntu may work fine on your computer, but a more light lightweight flavor of Ubuntu like Xubuntu or Lubuntu would probably operate faster and smoother on your machine. They were created with PCs with lower end hardware in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot of flavors, and the absolute best I have come upon performance-wise, and appearance wise (in my opinion) is Xubuntu. Actually, I had installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and then installed the XFCE desktop environment, but installing Xubuntu directly would be a lot more straightforward. Here's a link to where you can get [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/)...Hope this helps!